# Is there an advantage of using parentheses in decltype over explicitly typing const ref

Tags: c++, decltype

Which is better:

```
decltype((foo)) x = bar;
const decltype(foo)& x = bar;
```

If these are just two ways of saying the same thing, why are the parentheses even part of the language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to declare "a reference to the same type of object as `foo`", then I would prefer the second option.  That's not really what the other form of `decltype` is for.

The `decltype` keyword pulls double-duty:

1. It tells you the type of a variable
2. It tells you the type and *value category* of an expression

That's what the extra parenthesis do.  `foo` is an identifier, so `decltype(foo)` will tell you the type of the object identified by that identifier.  `(foo)` is not an identifier; it is an expression, so `decltype((foo))` will tell you both the type and value category of it.  It returns an lvalue-reference for an lvalue expression, an rvalue-reference for an xvalue, and a non-reference type for a prvalue.

For example:

```
int i = 10;
using A = decltype(i);            // A is an alias for int
                                  // because i is an identifer
using B = decltype((i));          // B is an alias for int&
                                  // because (i) is an lvalue expression
using C = decltype(std::move(i)); // C is an alias for int&&
                                  // because std::move(i) is an xvalue
                                  // expression
using D = decltype(i + 1);        // D is an alias for int
                                  // because i + 1 is a prvalue expression
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab21574f87fcde28)

The value categories of all of the expressions in that example are obvious from looking at them, but consider a template:

```
template <typename Func>
void foo(Func func)
{
    func(42);
}
```

The expression `func(42)` could result in any value category, depending on the exact return type.  That's where the expression form of `decltype` becomes useful.